# I can't find the button pressed in the UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

For the program that I'm developing, I've created a class `Utilities` that contains an alert view with a cancel button. I want to create one NSLog that advises me when the cancel button is pressed.
The method that contains the alert view is called in another class, that is the ViewController.m file, but at the moment no log appears. Can you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

**This is the Utilities.h file:**

```
@interface Utilities : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
    -(BOOL) isOnline;
@end
```

**This is the Utilities.m file:**

```
-(BOOL) isOnline {
    Boolean online = false;
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];
    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(status == ReachableViaWiFi) {
        NSLog(@"WI FI");
        online = true;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO WI FI");
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                          message:@"You are not connected to a wireless network. Please connect your device."
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];    
    }

    return online;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex::(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {

          NSLog(@"Clicked the button Ok");
    }
}
```

And here is where I call the method in the `ViewController` class:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     //Add gradient background
     CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
 bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
     [self initialize];
     Utilities* utilities = [[Utilities alloc] init]; //create an istance of the class Utilities for use their methods in this class
     [utilities isOnline]; //call the method isOnline from the class Utilities
}
```

**Update: here there is the error message that now is returning to me Xcode**:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558670'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x1809012 0x162ee7e 0x18944bd 0x17f8bbc 0x17f894e 0xb30e13 0x778d66 0x778f04 0x2027d8 0x1dd4014 0x1dc47d5 0x17afaf5 0x17aef44 0x17aee1b 0x268f7e3 0x268f668 0x73affc 0x2133 0x20c5)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception"

Comment: I'm updating the question following the help given to me. It isn't working yet, so i will add a comment and update all. Please give me a minute :)

Comment: Also, the return type of `isOnline` should be `BOOL` not `Boolean`. And you don't need to declare the method `- (void)alertView` in the header.

Comment: OK, I think something is wrong here. The class `Utilities` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Are you using the `Utilities` class to display stuff on the screen (not including the alert view)? If not then it should probably be a `NSObject`.

Comment: I see. You have to retain `Utilities` somewhere. Put them into a `strong` property. The `Utilities` work as the delegate but they are not retained anywhere.

Comment: the utilities class is under UIViewController, because in the .h file i have added "@interface Utilities : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>{ }". At the moment the utilities class show only the AlertView. So i have to change it?

Comment: Yeah, change it to `@interface Utilities: NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>`. ... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister That's not really needed. It is strange but it's not a problem.

Comment: @Sulthan No, but editing my answer to pick up the property thing. It shouldn't be released under ARC but I think you might be right.

Comment: I try to change it for test, and in this case xcode return another error: "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0xb0753fc4)". So now isn't code2 how before, but code1.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have already edited my answer, too :) It should be deallocated because there is no strong reference. The `alertView` holds the delegate only weakly so ARC should definitely deallocate it.

Comment: Of course. The only link is from the AlertView. I gave you +1 for spotting that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate method you want is...

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Not sure why but you've changed the method name to `buttonPressed:...`.

If you change this back it should work. As long as you've connected the delegate properly.

As mentioned elsewhere, you probably want to use `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` to avoid making UI changes when the alert view is still visible.

**EDIT**

OK, after further conversations...

Change your interface to...

```
@interface Utilities : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>

    -(BOOL) isOnline;
@end
```

Change the interface of `iPhoneHttpserverViewcontroller` to...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Utilities *utilities;
```

And change you viewWillAppear to...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     //Add gradient background
     CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
 bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
     [self initialize];

     // I've edited these next two lines to use the property.
     self.utilities = [[Utilities alloc] init]; //create an istance of the class Utilities for use their methods in this class
     [self.utilities isOnline]; //call the method isOnline from the class Utilities
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have updated now the code, you can see it in the question, but the NSLog isn't appearing yet.

Comment: Is the delegate method being called at all? Have you set a breakpoint in it to check?

Comment: I set a breakpoint when i call the isOnline method, but i'm not seeing  strange things or errors. Have i to search something in particular?

Comment: No, set a breakpoint in the `alertView:didDismiss...` method. If the alert view is going away when you press the "OK" button then this method will be getting called. You just need to check logic inside.

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems that program doesn't enter in the breakpoint. When i click the ok button it goes directly in the error and doesn't show me informations about breakpoint. Now i saw that it is returning this error: alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: OK, what's the instance type in the error. Can you put the error message into the question please (in full).

Comment: i have added it at the bottom of my question. Thanks. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @Hieicker ok, I edited my answer. Hopefully this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The problem now is at compiling time. It give: " Property 'utilities' not found on object of type 'iPhoneHTTPServerViewController'   ".
iPhoneHttpserverViewcontroller is the main class of the program.

Comment: Thank you very much to @Fogmeister now it works perfect! You help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
buttonPressed:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

is not a delegate method, the correct method is

```
alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

However, usually people use

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

because you don't want to perform another UI actions when the alert is still visible.

Also make sure to use the following for index comparison

```
if (buttonIndex == alert.cancelButtonIndex) { ...
```

**Edit:**

Since the `utilities` are used as the delegate, you have to retain them otherwise they will get deallocated

```
@interface ViewController : ... ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIUtilities* utilities.

@end

...

self.utilities = [[Utilities alloc] init];
[self.utilities isOnline]
```

Comment: thanks for help. I have updated now the code, you can see it in the question, but the NSLog isn't appearing yet. When i click the "ok" button i receive this error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2, address=0x27)

Comment: Isn't the UIAlertView instance out of scope at the end of viewWillAppear? Doesn't it need to be retained?

Comment: Sincerely i don't know. I follow only some tutorials for create the alert view because i'm new on the objective c language. What do you mean with "retained" ? Do you think that the resource is release too early?

Comment: If you're using ARC then you don't have to retain anything. If you're not using ARC... use ARC.

Comment: If possible i use always ARC.

Answer (score -2):

Please use Custom Alert View and add button like "Cancel" or "Ok". So you can achieve your goal.For

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

Comment: Is the only way for resolve my problem? The standard UiAlertView can't work in this mode?

Comment: These are the sample links those may be use to create Custom Alert but you have to change Clickevent type : 

>> https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wcalertview 
>> https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alertview
>> https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sialertview

Comment: No, this is wrong. You can get the button press from the delegate methods.

Comment: why this is wrong? Take any button and try it. U can handle action event by press on Button.

Comment: yeah, but telling him to use a custom alert view? jusr use the standard one with a delegate.

Comment: I have mentioned before answer that he has to use Custom Alert View.And everywhere I have used Custom Alert View word

Comment: if you want to reinvent the wheel then be my guest. I'll stick with the standard one that does everything I need. By following your instruction you're also missing the point of delegation.

Comment: ... erm... you mean like in my answer?